# Rename git directory cloned from Openshift

Tags: openshift

I renamed the cloned directory and now `rhc` commands like `rhc app-show -v` require me to pass additional parameter of application with `-a` option.
How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Simply clone like this instead of renaming,

```
git clone https://github.com/user/userApp.git name_you_want
```

this command will clone your app in the name what you specified after that clone http command

Comment: Is there any easy way to rename the application ?

Comment: you mean after clone application into your system?

Comment: No. I meant change application name after you have created a new application.